# Topological charges and universal gravity

Tags: gravity, topological-field-theory

After reading two days ago a paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.10365, I read that topological charges DO NOT gravitate. Is that statement right? Why I have doubts:

1. Topological charges have "energy".
2. Energy couple to gravity.
   Then, even if the topological charge does not couple directly to the metric tensor, wouldn't it enter through energy-momentum?
   Given the fact that there are Chern-Simons field theories and Chern-Simons gravities, I don't agree with the statement of the paper either.
   What is then happening?